# VBA: How to compare values of changing cells in a column with another dynamic range?

Tags: vba, excel

[I have a list of 500 orders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvRpc.png), each with a product code. I don't know how many different product codes exist (there are multiple orders for the same product code). I need to write a Macro code to find all the existing product codes and paste them in the column L.

The first product code will be pasted in column L as is. Now,  as this continues I want the next product code from column C to be checked with all the values that have been entered in column L, i.e., for eg, if A01 has already been pasted in column L then when A01 occurs the next time in Column C, I don't want it to be pasted in Column L.

What I mean is I want to find all the unique product codes I have.
I have accomplished this by recording a data filter (Ascending) marco but I want to know how this can be done by writing my own code.
Thanks a lot in advance! :)

```
Sub try()

    Dim j as long

    Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long



    lastrow = Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
    On Error GoTo 0

    Range("C2").Select
    Selection.Copy Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L2")

    For i = 3 to lastrow

    j = Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1

       If Range("C" & i).value <> Range("L2:L" & j - 1).value Then 'Here's what I don't know how to write

       Range("C" & i).select

       Selection.Copy Workbooks("A.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L" & j)

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: The easiest way is to copy all the codes to the target column then remove duplicates from that column. Would that suffice?

Comment: Another option could be to use [`Range.Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx), and if it is not found move it over.

Answer (score 2):

Copy all codes into the target column then remove the duplicates from it:

```
Sheet1.Columns("C").Copy Sheet1.Columns("L")
Sheet1.Columns("L").RemoveDuplicates 1
```